# saving values from a range loop calculation

Tags: python, pandas, list

Hopefully this isn't a silly question, but I am running into some issues trying to utilize a `range()` loop to make a calculations from a saved machine learning model, and then totalize all of the calculated values at the end. Every time the `range():` loop executes this will return a numpy array of `estimatedKwh`. I am attempting to store the values in `total_estKwh` and if I start at zero for `total_estKwh` how do I append `total_estKwh`... And then totalize it after the `range()` loop finishes?

```
total_rows = len(data.index)
row_num = 0
total_estKwh = 0

for i in range(total_rows):
    params = np.array(data.iloc[row_num])

    if (params.ndim == 1):
        params = np.array([params])

    estimatedKwh = load_trained_model(weights_path).predict(params)
    print("Estimated kWH:", int(estimatedKwh))

    estimatedKwh = pd.DataFrame(estimatedKwh)
    estimatedKwh.append(total_estKwh)


    row_num += 1

#total_estKwh = pd.DataFrame(total_estKwh)

#print("FINISHED, total Estimated kWH:", total_estKwh)
print(total_estKwh)
```

The code doesn't work... This is the traceback of what I am attempting... Any tips help thank you

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Estimated kWH: 1083
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bbartling\Desktop\EC\ecPredic2.py", line 70, in <module>
    estimatedKwh.append(total_estKwh)
  File "C:\Users\bbartling\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 6211, in append
    sort=sort)
  File "C:\Users\bbartling\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py", line 225, in concat
    copy=copy, sort=sort)
  File "C:\Users\bbartling\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py", line 286, in __init__
    raise TypeError(msg)
TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type "<class 'int'>"; only pd.Series, pd.DataFrame, and pd.Panel (deprecated) objs are valid
>>>
```

Comment: As the error says, you're trying to concatenate an integer (`total_estKw`) but you can only concatenate those types : `pd.Series, pd.DataFrame, and pd.Panel` so try with one of those i guess

Comment: total_estKwh = [ ]

and you are done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you are actually trying to achieve this could be one way.

```
data = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(100))

all_estimates =[]

for i, row in data.iterrows():
    params = row.values

    if (params.ndim == 1):
        params = np.array([params])

    #estimatedKwh = load_trained_model(weights_path).predict(params)
    estimatedKwh = np.array([1.2]) # A dummy value for this example 
    all_estimates.append(estimatedKwh)

df = pd.DataFrame(all_estimates)
total_estKwh = df.sum() # Total for all_estimates
```

Comment: @HenryHub obviously I didn't mean to un-accept my own answer (although it is your question, and you are perfectly free to do so); what I meant was to *upvote* (you can only accept one answer, but you can upvote all of them if they have been helpful)...

Comment: @desertnaut, Yeah sorry I its a close toss up here and thanks for your help... Would you be able to help me with this post by chance? https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/48145/looping-program-for-mlp-keras-prediction

Answer (score 1):

(since the discussion in the comments seems to go nowhere...)

You cannot append integers, but you can append *lists*; so, just forget the pandas dataframes and work with lists:

1) Initialize `total_estKwh` as

```
total_estKwh = []
```

2) Remove `estimatedKwh = pd.DataFrame(estimatedKwh)`

3) Replace `estimatedKwh.append(total_estKwh)` with

```
total_estKwh.append(estimatedKwh)
```

If you definitely want to end up with a pandas daraframe, you can always convert the list after the `for` loop...